# EWS and AutoDiscoverURL error using Azure AD Certificate with Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, exchangewebservices

I've tried with and without Secret ID, and now with a self-signed Certificate and I keep getting the same error:

> Exception calling "AutodiscoverUrl" with "2" argument(s): "The
> expected XML node type was XmlDeclaration, but the actual type is
> Element."

My PowerShell script:

```
$TenantId = "blahblah"
$AppClientId="blahblah"
$EDIcertThumbPrint = "blahblah"
$EDIcert = get-childitem Cert:\CurrentUser\My\$EDIcertThumbPrint

$MsalParams = @{
    ClientId = $AppClientId
    TenantId = $TenantId
    ClientCertificate = $EDIcert
    Scopes = "https://outlook.office.com/.default"
}
$MsalResponse = Get-MsalToken @MsalParams
$EWSAccessToken  = $MsalResponse.AccessToken

Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll'

#Provide the mailbox id (email address) to connect via AutoDiscover
$MailboxName ="email@myemaildomain.com.au"
$ews = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService]::new()
$ews.Credentials = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.OAuthCredentials]$EWSAccessToken
$ews.Url = "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"
$ews.AutodiscoverUrl($MailboxName,{$true})
```

I've searched that error message everywhere, and I am not getting anywhere. The error doesn't make sense, because I am not referring to XML in any way - unless it's embedded inside the EWS?

The only time this works is when I don't use either a Secret ID nor a Certificate, but the Token only lasts 1 hour! I need to make this automatic, so I can get into my mailbox and extract files from emails.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

So I've removed the AutoDiscoverUrl() and I now getting another error:

> Exception calling "FindItems" with "2" argument(s): "The request
> failed. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

Trace log:

```
The token contains not enough scope to make this call.";error_category="invalid_grant"
```

But why when I have an Oauth token!?

My code in trying to open the "Inbox":

```
$results = $ews.FindItems(
    "Inbox",
    ( New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView -ArgumentList 100 )
)
$MailItems = $results.Items | where hasattachments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoDiscoverv1 doesn't support the client credentials flow so you need to remove the line

> $ews.AutodiscoverUrl($MailboxName,{$true})

It's redundant anyway because your already setting the EWS endpoint eg

> $ews.Url = "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"

The only time that endpoint would change is if you had mailbox OnPrem in a hybrid environment and there are other ways you can go about detecting that such as autodiscoverv2.

Comment: Thank you for that. So I thought this was the case, and skipped the AutoDiscoverUrl() entirely, but when I try to look into the "Inbox" folder, I get Exception calling "FindItems" with "2" argument(s): "The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (403)
Forbidden.". I've updated my OP

Comment: I traced the EWS calls and noticed this: The token contains not enough scope to make this call.";error_category="invalid_grant".

Comment: Again, if I remove the Secrets or Cert IDs from the $MsalParams, it works, but again I have to manually re-enter username and password. Doesn't make sense if I am already providing the secretID. I've also followed the steps here for Configure for App Only Authentication https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth

Comment: You can check the token itself using jwt.io it should contain the full_access_as_app scope it sounds like this isn't happening has the permission been consented to ?

Comment: You also need to make sure that your using Impersonation in EWS I can't see you doing that in your code. Also any reason you using EWS vs the Graph ? you may find using the Graph PowerShell SDK is a lot easier, EWS is no consider legacy and should only be used when there is no alternative.

Comment: Solved it thanks to your last comments - yes [1] I was missing the permission granted for the permissions I set up, so someone higher than me needed to approve my App permissions and [2] yes I was missing the Impersonation part. Works perfectly now! Thank you. You should probably update your answer with those two parts, as it had nothing to do with AutoDiscover, which also works now.